# Azure Cosmos DB - order by a version string

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Currently I have a list of documents in a collection. Each document has a `version` string field which I would like to order by. Although this example query does not work, I'm looking for something similar to the following. `select * from p order by p.version desc` I believe this may be possible using a stored procedure but is that the most efficient way if it is possible?

```
{
  "productId": "...",
  "version": "3.6.2",
  "platform": "..."
},
{
  "productId": "...",
  "version": "2.2.1",
  "platform": "..."
},
{
  "productId": "...",
  "version": "7.4.8",
  "platform": "..."
},
{
  "productId": "...",
  "version": "2.2.6",
  "platform": "..."
}
```

Comment: Probably better off storing the major, minor, and patch properties separately and having a composite index on all three to get the correct semantic ordering efficiently

Comment: Are you getting an error? Or you're just not able to sort by version number?

Comment: I'd like to sort based on the individual components of the version rather than the version string as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to sort based on the individual components of the version
>   rather than the version string as a whole.

Basically, [we are told](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/11/06/a-few-cosmosdb-query-limitations/) we can only sort with properties of document, not derived values.So,you can't sort data like `order by substring(version,0,1)`.

2 ways as workaround:

1.Follow @Martion's suggestion: Split `version` according to `.` into three properties and add them into your documents so that you could sort them as normal.

2.Select three derived properties in sql:

```
SELECT substring(c.version,0,1) as major,substring(c.version,2,1) as minor,substring(c.version,4,1) as patch FROM c
```

Then sort the result in the code,like [Array.Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Thank you for the response - I had thought about the second option but as soon as versions grow beyond a single digit, "10.0.0" for example, I'm hosed.

Comment: @Hamer You may could set the priority of sort. Major>minor>patch.

Comment: @Hamer Hi,any progress here?

Comment: The only viable solution for this that I could see was requiring the database model to be updated to break these items up into individual pieces.

Comment: PS: don't use stored procedures for high volume reads. stored procs run only on the leader replica so don't use provisioned throughput efficiently. Stored procs are best choice for either high volume writes, particularly multi-document writes on the same partition.